# How would I fix this whitespace from appearing on the sides whenever I am showing the snakes length?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Whenever I run my program I check to see if I would place down 3 os it goes to the right. I know that the problem is that I have a bunch of if statements that cycle through, but I have a for loop there to place down the snakes trail. I know that all those ifs aren't good.

I tried changing in the top of the for loop to be a if statement that was always true, it didn't work nothing did. I am confused on how to check for all of the coordinates, but still not have the walls pop up on the sides.

I am a begginer, so don't hate on my code that much.

````
snake.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <random>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "snake.hpp"
    void endGame(int score);
    
    const int KEY_ARROW_CHAR1 = 224;
    const int KEY_ARROW_UP = 72;
    const int KEY_ARROW_DOWN = 80;
    const int KEY_ARROW_LEFT = 75;
    const int KEY_ARROW_RIGHT = 77;
    
    void snake::input() {
        // checks for arrow key input
        if (_kbhit()) {
            //stores keycode
            int key = _getch();
            //checks if key is arrow key
            if (key == KEY_ARROW_CHAR1) {
                //stores arrow key
                key = _getch();
                //checks if arrow key is up
                if (key == KEY_ARROW_UP) {
                    direction = '^';
                }
                //checks if arrow key is down
                else if (key == KEY_ARROW_DOWN) {
                    direction = 'v';
                }
                //checks if arrow key is left
                else if (key == KEY_ARROW_LEFT) {
                    direction = '<';
                }
                //checks if arrow key is right
                else if(key == KEY_ARROW_RIGHT) {
                    direction = '>';
                }
            }
        } 
        switch (direction) {
        case '^':
            snakeCoords[2]--;
            break;
        case 'v':
            snakeCoords[2]++;
            break;
        case '>':
            snakeCoords[0]++;
            break;
        case '<':
            snakeCoords[0]--;
        }
        checkForObjects();
    }
    bool snake::checkForObjects() {
        if ((snakeCoords[0] == 40 || snakeCoords[0] ==  0) || (snakeCoords[2] == 20 || snakeCoords[2] == 0)) {
            endGame(score);
        }
        if (snakeCoords[0] == fruitCoords[0] && snakeCoords[2] == fruitCoords[2]) {
            score++;
            getFruitLoc();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void snake::getFruitLoc() { 
        srand(time(0));
        fruitCoords[0] = rand() % 39;
        fruitCoords[2] = rand() % 19;
    }
    void endGame(int score) {
        std::cout << "you died, your score was  " << score;
        exit(0);
    }
    

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <random>
#include "snake.hpp"
#include <vector>
void createArena(char direction);
//Coordinates for snake
std::vector <std::vector<int>> previousCoords{
    {14, 10},
    {13, 10},
    {12, 10}
};

snake coordManager{};
int score{0};
int main()
{
    //make terminal green
    system("color 0a");
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "\t" << score;
        //pushes ascii arena down
        for (size_t i{}; i <= 5; i++) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        score = coordManager.score;
        //updates snake based on coordinates
        createArena(coordManager.direction);
        //manages all snake movements
        coordManager.input();
        //reminder this clears the screan
        system("CLS");
    }
    
}
void createArena(char direction) {
    //offsets screen
    
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t";
    for (size_t y{}; y <= 20; y++) {
        for (size_t x{}; x <= 40; x++) {
            //checks if it hits the snakes coordinates
            for (size_t i{}; i < previousCoords.size();) {
                 if (x == previousCoords.at(i).at(0) && y == previousCoords.at(i).at(1)) {
                    std::cout << "O";
                 }
                 i++;
            }     
            if (coordManager.snakeCoords[0] == x && coordManager.snakeCoords[2] == y) {
                std::cout << direction;
            }  
            else if (x == 0 || x == 40) {
                std::cout << '|';
            }
            else if (y == 0 || y == 20) {
                std::cout << '-';
            }
            else if(coordManager.fruitCoords[0] == x && coordManager.fruitCoords[2] == y) {
                std::cout << "F";
            }
            
            else {
                std::cout << " ";
            }
        }
        
        //offsets again
        std::cout << std::endl << "\t\t\t\t";
    }
}
````

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <random>
    #include <time.h>
    
    class snake {
    public:
        void input();
        bool checkForObjects();
        int score{};
        int snakeCoords[2]{
            /* X */ 15,
            /* Y */ 10
        };
        int fruitCoords[2]{
            /* X */  rand() % 39,
            /* Y */  rand() % 19
        };
        char direction{'O'};
    private:
        void getFruitLoc();
    };


https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdSNf.png
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem description. Maybe post an example of what you see, and what you were hoping to see, and then clean up the prose a bit.

Comment: This is one of the rare times where a picture could be helpful, though if you can get the formatting right, the erroneous output as text is the best option for everyone.

Comment: It looks like you should either add in snake.hpp so we can build and run your program so we can see shat you see, or you should back up your code and take an axe to it, carving it up into a small, complete example that demonstrates one problem you're having. Use [mre] for inspiration. You may find part way into making the smaller example that the bug jumps out at you and you can fix it. Less code means less room for bugs to hide.

Comment: Ill try that, it is hard for me to show my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, I used a boolean that I would change if it was different from whitespace. it was a simple fix sorry.